# When stop one consumer and start it instantly, the consumer group needs about 10 seconds to do rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka

**1. problem desc**

If stop one consumer and start this consumer instantly, the consumer group needs about 10 seconds to do rebalance.

But if stop one consumer and wait for about 10s, then start that consumer, this problem will not appear.

**2. Env**

kakfa-version:0.11.0.1

**3. demo**

1. Producer1Demo.java(Producer-A send message to topic:topic1)
2. Producer2Demo.java(Producer-B send message to topic:topic2)
3. Consumer1Demo.java(Consumer-A get message from topic:topic1)
4. Consumer2Demo.java(Consumer-B get message from topic:topic2)

Consumer-A and Consumer-B in same group group1,
the producer's codes like below

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "ip:9092");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        boolean flag = true;
        int i = 0;
        while(flag){
            if(i>=1000){
                flag = false;
            }
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord("topic1", "topic<1>-"+ i));
            i++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        producer.close();
    }
```

The consumer's codes like below

```
 public static void main(String []args){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "ip:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "group1");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topic1"));
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
        consumer.close();
    }
```

**4.how to reappear this problem**

1. First start above four java's main method, then, Consumer-A and
   Consumer-B can get message from their corresponding topic
   continuously
2. Then, I stop the Consumer1Demo.java's process and start
   Consumer1Demo.java's main method instantly, Consumer-B will bock for
   about 10 seconds to rejoin group group1, below is Consumer-A's log's
   log:

`Discovered coordinator 10.105.168.92:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) for group group1.
 Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group group1
 (Re-)joining group group1
<will sleep about 10s>
 Successfully joined group group1 with generation 52
 Setting newly assigned partitions [topic1-0, topic1-1, topic1-6, topic1-7, topic1-2, topic1-3, topic1-4, topic1-5] for group group1`

Consumer-B's log

 `Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic2-0, topic2-1, topic2-2, topic2-7, topic2-3, topic2-4, topic2-5, topic2-6] for group group1
 (Re-)joining group group1
<will sleep about 10s>
 Successfully joined group group1 with generation 52
 Setting newly assigned partitions [topic2-0, topic2-1, topic2-2, topic2-7, topic2-3, topic2-4, topic2-5, topic2-6] for group group1
offset = 215, key = null, value = testMessageTopic<2>-318`

**Through log, we can see, the Consumer-A and Consumer-B will also cost about 10 seconds to join the group, it seems they both need to get generation same value:52, this step seems to cost 10 seconds.**

**5.How to avoid this problem.**

1. First, stop Consumer-A process, and wait about 15 seconds, then,
   start Consumer1Demo.java main to start Consumer-A, this problem will gone.
2. Then let's analyze the log.

<5.2.1>Before doing step1, the Consumer-A and Consumer-B's generation value are also 63
<5.2.2>after stop Consumer-A process, Consumer-B will rejoin the group instantly and get the generation value:64

<5.2.3>after wait about 15 seconds, start Consumer1Demo.java main again. the Consumer-A will rejoin the group instantly and get the generation value:65

<5.2.4>Then, Consumer-B will also rejoin the group with the generation value:65 when the generation value is changed due to Consumer-A rejoin again.

**5.The root reason**

1. When one consumer's down, consumer group will rebalance and get new
   generation value(oldValue + 1)
2. When one consumer startup, consumber group will also do rebalance
   and get new generation value(oldValue + 1)

In this case, it seems step5.1 and step5.2 happen at the same time, so may exist resource competition, so the coordinator may cost 10 seconds to solve the problem.

**6.my question**

I don't know whether I analyzed the problem right, there was another reason?

Comment: How did you stop the consumer? If the process was shutdown abruptly(kill -9 for instance), the coordinator might take a while to realize its failure, although it should be definitely no larger than `session.timeout.ms`.

Comment: Stop the consumer by click intellij idea's stop button, then, run the consumer's main instantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the two consumer1 and consumer2 in same consumer group,when restart or stop one of the consumers, the consumer group will do `do rebalance` operation, it will cost about 10s.

After changed to different consumer groups, the problem gone.